# Python probability from a random sample

Tags: python, numpy, random, probability, sample

Here's what I'd like to do : There's 47% of girls amongst a population of 200 people. After choosing a random sample of 24 persons, I have to find the probability of having between 6 to 9 girls in that sample. I've been trying many ways but each of them just turn out wrong!

Could you help me out using NUMPY and LOOP?

Here's what I did :

```
import numpy as np 

population=np.random.choice(np.arange(0,2),size=200, p=[0.53, 0.47])
```

and I just don't know how to create a loop like: `for in range(6,9)` from my 24 persons sample?

Comment: You would have to sample many samples of 24 people from your population, and then check what percentage of the samples have 6,7,8 or 9 girls in them.

Answer (score 2):

Although i'd prefer to simply use mathmatics to solve this question, there is a way of how you can approximate the wanted probability by means of Monte-Carlo simulation. I've worked out both approaches here.

### Monte-Carlo approach

From what your text tells us, there **are 47% of girls** in a population of 200 people. So you shouldn't use `np.random.choise()` to get the population, instead you should generate a set of 200 persons with 106 male and 94 female persons, where `0` represents a male person and `1` represents a female person:

```
population = [0] * 106 + [1] * 94
```

From that set, you have to randomly pick 24 persons:

```
subpopulation = np.random.choice(population, size=24)
```

To evaluate the number of female persons in that subset, simply sum up the array with:

```
female_count = np.sum(subpopulation)
```

The calculate the overall probabilty of having 6 to 9 girls in the random choice of 24 persons from the set of 200 persons, repeat this random test several time (e.g. N = 100000) and count how often `female_count` is within a range of 6 to 9:

```
import numpy as np

population = [0] * 106 + [1] * 94
N = 100000
count_in_range = 0

for _ in range(N):
    subpopulation = np.random.choice(population, size=24)
    female_count = np.sum(subpopulation)

    if female_count in range(6, 10):  # 10 is not included 
        count_in_range += 1


in_range_probabilty = count_in_range/N
print(f'p = {in_range_probabilty}')
```

### Exact approach

To calculate the exact probabilty, simply use the [Binomial Distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_distribution) to calculate probabilities that of that 24 persons are exactly 6 persons female, 7 persons female and so forth and sum up those probabilties:

```
import scipy.special
p = 0.47
n = 24

p_exact = 0
for k in range(6,10):
    p_exact += scipy.special.binom(n,k) * p**k * (1-p)**(n-k)

print(f'p_exact = {p_exact}')
```

### Sample output:

```
p = 0.226853
p_exact = 0.22672292898157842
```

Please note, that result of `p` may vary upon different runs, as this is randomly generated, whereas `p_exact` is the mathmatical exact probabilty and remains the same all the time.

Comment: Thanks you're awesome !!

Answer (score 1):

I suppose in this case we are talking about drawing without replacement from a population so it is a hypergeometric distribution and its probability mass function (pmf) is given by:

[image]

where

> M is the population size, 200 in this example
>
> n is the number of girls in the population, 0.47*200 = 94
>
> N is the number of draws, 24
>
> k is the number of observed successes, no of girls

We use [hypergeom from scipy](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.14.0/reference/generated/scipy.stats.hypergeom.html):

```
from scipy.stats import hypergeom
rv = hypergeom(200,94,24)
sum(rv.pmf([6,7,8,9]))
0.21462937817887562
```

So the probability is 0.21462937817887562

Comment: Hello, many thanks for you help :) Do you know any alternatives using Numpy and a Loop ???

Comment: Sorry can you elaborate on looping through what? It's really vague

Comment: Here's what I did : " import numpy as np
population=np.random.choice(np.arange(0,2),size=200, p=[0.53, 0.47]), and I just don't know how to create a loop like : "for in range(6,9)" from my 24 persons sample ? Thank you so much !!!!!